# calculate the total and display

Tags: javascript

I have array with decimal value 1.19, 1.44, 4.59 and so-on

How to calculate sum and alert.

Comment: summ += $(this).text() -- gives a NaN

Comment: @Mario That's because `text()` returns **string, not a number** (e.g. "12.5"). You need to type convert string to number before appending it to `sum` (e.g. by using `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `Number` functions or unary `+` operator). See http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html for explanation of type conversion.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jquery for this, plain javascript is okay:

```
var tot = 0.0;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    tot += array[i];
alert(tot);
```

Comment: `0` will do just fine, no need for `0.0` really :)

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to Davide's answer with JQuery each :

```
<script>
var arr = [ 1.19, 1.44, 4.59 ];
var sum = 0;

jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  sum += this;
});

alert(sum);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function GetSum()
   { 
   var mynumbers = new Array(1.19, 1.44, 4.59,5.67);

    var sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<=mynumbers.length-1; i++)
  {

  sum = sum + parseFloat(mynumbers[i]);
  }
  alert(sum);
  }
```